# How to index on date in FHIR?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

In Fhir we have a parameter called `_content` which does the search on entire text of the single document.

For example, let's say we have patients who have the last name as Bauch then we can search the patient something like

`http://localhost:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/Patient?_content=Bauch`.

I am getting the proper results if I try the above query.

The same way I wanted to search based on birthdate. something like this:-

`http://localhost:8080/hapi-fhir-jpaserver/fhir/Patient?_content=20-12-2010`, but I am not getting any results.

Looks like there is indexing on text fields. Is there any way to add indexing on birthdate?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736595/how-to-index-on-date-in-fhir?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search birthData in fhir using \_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733954/how-to-search-birthdata-in-fhir-using-content)